# MySql, Starting XA crash recovery

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Mysql server crashed on my ec2 server, Sometimes it works without problems and sometimes it crashes suddenly, which causes bugs in my project.

**My Server Details**

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- 1 GB Ram

**This is mysql error log:-**

```
2020-10-12T16:06:15.527729Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 64634
2020-10-12T16:06:15.550683Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-10-12T16:06:16.347250Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-10-12T16:06:16.700702Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-10-12T16:06:16.741103Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2020-10-12T16:06:16.754582Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2020-10-12T16:06:16.826186Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-10-12T16:06:16.826443Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-10-12T16:06:16.878163Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
AWS EC2 model?, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Amazon Linux 2, also with 1 GB RAM machine.It's happening when I try to view my database on phpMyAdmin. And sometimes on the CLI as well. Perhaps we need more memory.

Comment: Yeah you are right we need more memory, so you can use **AWS RDS** (Relational Database Service), it support free trial.

Comment: @MohamedAli I confirmed with `dmesg` that MySQL did run out of memory. I think I set my `innodb_buffer_pool_size` too high. Already provisioned an 8GB ec2 instance to resolve the issue.